# Efficient way to write a method for outputting time in a specific city

Tags: c#, datetime, timezone

Ok so there has got to be a more efficient way to do this, but i seem to be having a bit of coder's block.

I have a text box that allows users to enter a city and determine time in that city. I wanted to group the cities by Time Zones. Here is my existing code that works fine:

```
string stringToCheck = cityBox.Text;
DateTime utc = DateTime.UtcNow;
```

For Mountain:

```
TimeZoneInfo MST = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Mountain Standard Time");
DateTime mst = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(utc, MST);
string[] zoneMST = { "denver","calgary","etc" };


foreach (string x in zoneMST)
{
     if (x.Contains(stringToCheck))
         {
           clockLabel.Content = mst.ToString("hh:mm tt");
         }
}
```

and for Central:

```
TimeZoneInfo CST = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Central Standard Time");
DateTime cst = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(utc, CST);
string[] zoneCST = { "kansas city","etc", };


foreach (string x in zoneCST)
{
     if (x.Contains(stringToCheck))
         {
           clockLabel.Content = cst.ToString("hh:mm tt");
         }
}
```

The issue is I have 185 Cities i need to do (which is why i grouped them by timezone) and there are 103 time zones.

**My question is, is there a better way to format this that will prevent me from having to repeat this code for each time zone?**

Comment: One option is to do an API call. EarthTools has a free one [here](http://www.earthtools.org/webservices.htm#timezone).

Comment: Nothing WPF specific in this question, removed tag.

Comment: @DeanK that limits the answers...the user wanted a possible WPF specific answer; to which I gave one.

Comment: @OmegaMan Tag restored...

Comment: @Reed Copsey Wondering why you removed the WPF tag again? The tag was originally submitted by the poster which means that the UI is WPF and I removed it thinking there is nothing WPF specific in the question but OmegaMan provided a WPF specific answer so I think this question should keep the WPF tag...

Comment: @DeanK. Yeah, I did - there's absolutely nothing WPF related in the question - so it seems weird to have the tag on there... Somebody looking for WPF content wouldn't find this useful.

Comment: @ReedCopsey I thought so myself but than OmegaMan provided a WPF specific answer with a Converter so now I think it should have the WPF tag after all?

Comment: @DeanK. I do'nt think the question should have it - since it has nothign to do with it.  OmegaMan included an explanation in the answer - so it makes sense in that context

Comment: FYI - Be careful when looking up just by a free-form city name.  Many city names are commonly found in more than one state or country.  For example, most people think of "Phoenix" as the capital of Arizona, but there are [six other cities in the US named Phoenix, two in Canada, and a few others](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phoenix#Places).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can build a collection that's a `Dictionary<string,List<string>>` representing the time zone, then cities per time zone:

```
var timeZoneDictionary = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>
{
     { "Mountain Standard Time", new List<string> { "Denver", "Calgary" } },
     { "Central Standard Time", new List<string> { "Kansas City" } }
};
```

Once you have that, you could easily run through and loop the entire thing:

```
foreach(var kvp in timeZoneDictionary)
{
    if(kvp.Value.Any(city => city == stringToCheck))
    {
        var timeZoneInfo = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(kvp.Key);
        var time = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(utc, timeZoneInfo);
        clockLabel.Content = time.ToString("hh:mm tt");
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: that's exactly what i was trying to come up with ha, thanks. however, im a little unfamiliar with dictionary. could you provide and example by chance? using the cities and timezones provided?

Comment: @LoganLower: How about you look up the [Dictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx) class on MSDN, read their example, and adapt it to your work?

Comment: @ReedCopsey thanks this looks great, although Visual Studio cannot find a definition for 'Keys'. I searched and wasn't able to find any reason this would be erroring out. im using: `using System.Collections.Generic`

Comment: @LoganLower Sorry - should be `kvp.Value.Any` - fixed

Comment: @ReedCopsey *sigh* I am always the brides maid...gave a WPF answer only to have someone remove the tag and by the time I answered, you got the reward. :-/ lol

Comment: @ReedCopsey sorry i know this is somewhat a second question, but would it be possible to make the city case insensitive? using an operator in the dictionary perhaps

Comment: sorry @OmegaMan **:/**

Comment: @LoganLower Yes - just change the lambda from `==` to some other mechanism, like http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c64xh8f9(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 2):

*Edit: User originally had WPF as a tag*

How about a WPF example?

This one requires a bit more work but it will pay off in the long run. The goal is to have the user type in a city and return which zone that city is in to a textblock. We will use a converter in the Xaml to do that work.

### Xaml

Working our way out from the xaml is the user input and the result in Xaml

```
<TextBox Name="UserInputCity" Text="{Binding City, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}"/>
<TextBlock Text="{Binding City, 
                 Converter={StaticResource ZoneConverter}, 
                 NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True}" />
```

Or first control on the screen takes the user input for the city and binds it to `City` on the ViewModel (or a INotifyPropertyChanged property on the current data context). The following control is a TextBlock control which will display which zone that city is in thanks to the use of a converter named 'ZoneConverter' in or code behind.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <conv:TimeZoneConverter x:Key="ZoneConverter" />
</Window.Resources>
```

### City Class

We will create a City Class object which our converter will use. It will hold the name of the city and the current time zone. Notice how we have UTC offset as the enums which can be used in the future:

```
public class City
{
    public enum eZones
    {
        Central = 5,
        Mountain = 6,
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public eZones Zone {  get; set; }

};
```

### Converter

Finally our converter which does the heavy lifting:

```
public class TimeZoneConverter : System.Windows.Data.IValueConverter
{
    public static IList<City> Cities = new List<City>
    {
        new City() { Name= "chicago", Zone = City.eZones.Central },
        new City() { Name= "denver", Zone = City.eZones.Mountain },
        new City() { Name= "calgary", Zone = City.eZones.Mountain }
    };


    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string result = "???";

        if ((value != null) && (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value.ToString() )))
        {
            var city = Cities.FirstOrDefault(town => town.Name == value.ToString().ToLower());

            if (city != null)
                result = city.Zone.ToString();

        }

        return result;

    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

This when the user types in `Denver` or `denver` `Mountain` is dutifully shown when focus is lost in the user text input box. Instead of showing `Mountain` the actual time could be shown instead by the converter, but the process has been demonstrated.

[image]

Comment: This will have a couple of problems when actually working with time zones.  Specifically, there are several time zones that have the same base UTC offset, even in North America.  For example, Arizona is UTC-7 year round, unlike the rest of Mountain time which alternates between UTC-7 and UTC-6 for DST.  Also, many of the identifiers required by `TimeZoneInfo` have spaces and punctuation characters that are not valid enum names.  Lastly, (IMHO) binding the application logic to the presentation layer is not such a great idea for separation of concerns, testability, etc.